# Bigquery SQL how to update rows AND Insert new data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m new here and starting a new project in Bigquery. I understand the SQL insert or update commands.  But my data is project operational data that comes in containing some rows with changes (needing update) and some rows that are new data (Insert).

How do I approach this problem. Do I need to code each row to either insert or update, or is there a select statement that can do both?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`merge` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement).

> A MERGE statement is a DML statement that can combine INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations into a single statement and perform the operations atomically.